# Pandas: Drop all records of duplicate indices

Tags: pandas, duplicates

I have a dataset with potentially duplicate records of the identifier `appkey`. The duplicated records should ideally not exist and therefore I take them to be data collection mistakes. I need to drop all instances of an `appkey` which occurs more than once.

The `drop_duplicates` method is not useful in this case (or is it?) as it either selects the first or the last of the duplicates. Is there any obvious idiom to achieve this with pandas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As of pandas version 0.12, we have `filter` for this. It does exactly what @Andy's solution does using `transform`, but a little more succinctly and somewhat faster.

```
df.groupby('AppKey').filter(lambda x: x.count() == 1)
```

To steal @Andy's example,

```
In [1]: df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [1, 4], [5, 6]], columns=['AppKey', 'B'])

In [2]: df.groupby('AppKey').filter(lambda x: x.count() == 1)
Out[2]: 
   AppKey  B
2       5  6
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was attempting and failing with since so long. Thanks for this.

Comment: Like I said, this is what I was trying. But I get this error: `TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable`. Any ideas? I know I am being really lazy here. Sorry for that.

Comment: silly me! Just when I think "ah ha I can use transform"... :)

Comment: Ah, crap! `pandas.__version__` is 0.10.1. I should smack myself on the head.

Comment: Hahaha, I was about to congratulate you for joining Team Transform when I realized this one belonged to Team Filter. :- D

Comment: Well, @asb, if upgrading is a hassle the transform trick is an option. Good luck!

Answer (score 7):

Here's one way, using a [transform](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#transformation) with count:

```
In [1]: df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [1, 4], [5, 6]], columns=['AppKey', 'B'])

In [2]: df
Out[2]:
   AppKey  B
0       1  2
1       1  4
2       5  6
```

Groupby the AppKey column and applying a transform count, means that each occurrence of AppKey is counted and the count is assigned to those rows where it appears:

```
In [3]: count_appkey = df.groupby('AppKey')['AppKey'].transform('count')

In [4]: count_appkey
Out[4]:
0    2
1    2
2    1
Name: AppKey, dtype: int64

In [5]: count_appkey == 1
Out[5]:
0    False
1    False
2     True
Name: AppKey, dtype: bool
```

You can then use this as a boolean mask to the original DataFrame (leaving only those rows whose AppKey occurs precisely once):

```
In [6]: df[count_appkey == 1]
Out[6]:
   AppKey  B
2       5  6
```

Answer (score 2):

In pandas version 0.17 the drop_duplicates function has a 'keep' parameter that can be set to 'False' to keep no duplicated entries (other options are keep='first' and keep='last'). So, in this case:

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset=['appkey'],keep=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

The following solution using [set operations](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#set-operations-on-index-objects) works for me.  It is significantly faster, though slightly more verbose, than the `filter` solution:

```py
In [1]: import pandas as pd
In [2]: def dropalldups(df, key):
   ...:     first = df.duplicated(key)  # really all *but* first
   ...:     last = df.duplicated(key, take_last=True)
   ...:     return df.reindex(df.index - df[first | last].index)
   ...: 
In [3]: df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [1, 4], [5, 6]], columns=['AppKey', 'B'])
In [4]: dropalldups(df, 'AppKey')
Out[4]: 
   AppKey  B
2       5  6

[1 rows x 2 columns]
In [5]: %timeit dropalldups(df, 'AppKey')
1000 loops, best of 3: 379 µs per loop
In [6]: %timeit df.groupby('AppKey').filter(lambda x: x.count() == 1)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.57 ms per loop
```

On larger datasets, the performance difference is much more dramatic.  Here are results for a DataFrame which has 44k rows.  The column I'm filtering on is a 6-character string.  There are 870 occurrences of 560 duplicate values:

```py
In [94]: %timeit dropalldups(eq, 'id')
10 loops, best of 3: 26.1 ms per loop
In [95]: %timeit eq.groupby('id').filter(lambda x: x.count() == 1)
1 loops, best of 3: 13.1 s per loop
```

Comment: Wow, I came back to this result after a long time. This is dramatic indeed. Thanks.