# With Pandas in Python, select only the rows where group by group count is 1

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've filtered my data as suggested here: [With Pandas in Python, select the highest value row for each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31361599/with-pandas-in-python-select-the-highest-value-row-for-each-group)

```
    author        cat  val
0  author1  category2   15
1  author2  category4    9
2  author3  category1    7
3  author3  category3    7
```

Now, I want to only get the authors present in this data frame once. I wrote this, but it doesn't work:

```
def where_just_one_exists(group):
        return group.loc[group.count() == 1]
most_expensive_single_category = most_expensive_for_each_model.groupby('author', as_index = False).apply(where_just_one_exists).reset_index(drop = True)
print most_expensive_single_category
```

Error:

```
  File "/home/mike/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1659, in check_bool_indexer
    raise IndexingError('Unalignable boolean Series key provided')
pandas.core.indexing.IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series key provided
```

My desired output is:

```
    author        cat  val
0  author1  category2   15
1  author2  category4    9
2  author3  category1    7
3  author3  category3    7
```

Comment: what's your desired output?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18851216/pandas-drop-all-records-of-duplicate-indices

Comment: I've added the desired output. Padraic's solution seems to be exactly what someone has suggested below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Easier

```
df.groupby('author').filter(lambda x: len(x)==1)


     author        cat  val
id                         
0   author1  category2   15
1   author2  category4    9
```

Comment: How would I sort it after applying count and mean? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31368918/with-pandas-in-python-how-do-i-sort-by-two-columns-which-are-created-by-the-agg

Answer (score 2):

my solution is a bit more complex but still working

```
def groupbyOneOccurrence(df):
    grouped = df.groupby("author")
    retDf = pd.DataFrame()
    for group in grouped:
        if len(group[1]._get_values) == 1:
            retDf = pd.concat([retDf, group[1]])
    return retDf


author        cat val
0  author1  category2  15
1  author2  category4   9
```