# With Pandas in Python, how do I sort by two columns which are created by the agg function?

Tags: python, pandas

For this sort of data

```
    author        cat  val
0  author1  category2   15
1  author2  category4    9
2  author3  category1    7
3  author4  category1    9
4  author5  category2   11
```

I want to get

```
      cat mean count
category2   13     2
category1    8     2
category4    9     1
```

I thought I was getting good at Pandas and wrote

```
most_expensive_standalone.groupby('cat').apply(['mean', 'count']).sort(['count', 'mean'])
```

but got

```
  File "/home/mike/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby.py", line 3862, in _intercept_function
    return _func_table.get(func, fnc)
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `.agg` instead `.apply` if you just want to pass two aggregate functions `mean` and `count` to your data. Also, since you've applied two functions on the same column `val`, it will introduce a multi-level column index. So before sorting on newly created columns `mean` and `count`, you need to select its outer level `val` first.

```
most_expensive_standalone.groupby('cat').agg(['mean', 'count'])['val'].sort(['mean', 'count']


           mean  count
cat                   
category1     8      2
category4     9      1
category2    13      2
```

Follow-ups:

```
# just perform groupby and .agg will give you this
most_expensive_standalone.groupby('cat').agg(['mean', 'count'])

           val      
          mean count
cat                 
category1    8     2
category2   13     2
category4    9     1
```

Select `val` column

```
most_expensive_standalone.groupby('cat').agg(['mean', 'count'])['val']


           mean  count
cat                   
category1     8      2
category2    13      2
category4     9      1
```

And finally call `.sort(['mean', 'count'])`

Comment: Works! Do you mind explaining this a bit more, please? "So before sorting on newly created columns mean and count, you need to select its outer level val first."

Comment: @Mike I've updated the post. Please have a look. :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot, mate! But how come selecting just val column doesn't lose the cat column?

Comment: @Mike cat is index instead of column. index is on axis=0, whereas column is on axis=1.